# Need help for displaying characters as a mirror at the same time as writing input

Tags: c#

I am new to this forum and working with Visual Studio as a beginner.
My teacher gave me an assignment to perform in Visual Studio but I don't have idea about it to implement

The assignment is to accept any input and simultaneously get it's output in mirrored form without the need to press Enter.

For example, 
If I am writing MESSI then at the the same time output should be ISSEM without pressing ENTER.

I tried my level best but without pressing ENTER I didn't get results. Here is my code :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test11
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter characters:");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(arr);
            string r = new string (arr);

            Console.WriteLine( s + " " + r);
        }

    }
}
```

So kindly help me for this problem

Regards,
OSCAR

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need to press enter with your code is that you are using `Console.ReadLine`, which doesn't return until you press enter.  You will want to look at using [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return each key as it is entered, and pass in `true` for the `intercept` parameter so that the input is not echoed to the console.  Look at the docs for [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you know how to interpret the input.

Since it's homework, I don't want to just give you the code, but here's some pseudo code to get you started.  If you run into specific issues, ask for further help.

```
initialize input string // use a StringBuilder
loop forever
{
    use Console.ReadKey(true) to get the next character
    if (user pressed enter)
        exit the loop // need some way to escape
    if (user entered printable character) // ignore control characters
    {
        add character to input string
        reverse string
        print reversed string
        move cursor to beginning of line // Console.Write('\r') will work here
    }
}
```

If you want to allow the backspace key to delete characters, you can check for that key, but you will also need to erase the previous output (just write spaces over it) before printing the new string, since it will be shorter.

You've already got most of the code, so hopefully this points you in the right direction to work out the rest.